# Enabling User Authorization on Hue AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, emr, apache-sentry, bigdata

We have been struggling with configuring Hue/AWS EMR to use user/role based authorization on AWS EMR using Apache Sentry.

we are following the cloudera's documentation (https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/sg_sentry_service_config.html)

We have been able to start the Sentry's service on the cluster and create/grant privileges to the users using sentry shell but after that beeline stopped working and we couldn't proceed any further.

Have anyone installed Apache Sentry and configured it then any help would be appreciated.